# Storing primitive datatypes in javascript

Tags: javascript

my question is how does javascript store its primitive in memory.

```
let num1 = "a"
let num2 = {value1: "a", value2: "b"}
let num3 = "a"
let num4 = ["a"]
let num5 = "a"
```

Does javascript create different "a"'s in memory? Or does it point to the same "a" every time?

Comment: Yes. Anything else wouldn't make sense though because if they were references to one 9 then it would take up even more memory (4 references plus one 9)!

Comment: Yes, numbers are value type objects. Read up on value vs reference objects.

Comment: @CherryDT are you saying a reference to a value in memory takes up space on memory? Can you please expand on that. I really think this is a good question. And could start a real conversation on the topic

Comment: @JustinMeskan Are you saying that references don't take up any space? That's revolutionary, instead of using memory we could store everything as references and store infinite amount of data for free!

Comment: @JustinMeskan yes it does because a pointer is also a value. It makes sense for a string that can take up a larger space, but not for a small integer like `9`. Not only does it take up more space but also it's less performant to access it.

Comment: I saw all the confusion by some of you so I modified my question to hopefully narrow down the edge cases you guys are getting stuck on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very good question! I personally think the answer is no, it does not store different a's in memory because:

- `num1 === num3` returns `true`

and

- `num1 === num2.value1` returns `true`

Prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove that Javascript only stores primitive values once is by using the "===" and "==" operators.

```
const obj1 = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "3"};
const obj2 = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "3"};
obj1 === obj2 // false
```

Obj1 and obj2 are different objects in two different places in memory.
Hence the reason obj1 === obj2 returned false.

```
let num1 = 9
let num2 = 9
num1 === num2 // true
```

Now the strictly equal line "num1 === num2" returns true
Because they are of the same type, value and reside in the same spot in memory

```
let num1 = "9"
let num2 = 9
num1 == num2 // true
num1 === num2 // false
```

They are equal using the double == signs because javascript will do a cool type conversion on one of them and then compare the two. But when you use the triple === you get false. Why? Because they are not in the same location in memory they are different values. Javascript is not compiled so it needs to keep as much memory free as possible and one of the ways it does that is by only storing each primitive value once in memory.